Queue of process at back end api
i need some help.
i did the code above, this is a function who external back end call and we need manage some informations and return they back. the problem is, they send MULTIPLES requests at same time (second) and our code process all at same time and that's wrong, because this manage balance of customers. so if they send for example 3 requests at same time it decrease funds of customer on first request, but accept second and last request without have but on balance. so i need receive all requests, queue that, process, and return for their back end.
how i can do that? i'm using laravel.
public function bmake(Request $request)
    {
        try {
            $data       = json_decode(json_encode($request->all()), true);
            $decoded    = $this->decodeJwt($data['payload']);
            $request    = $decoded['payload']->payload;

            if ($request->currency != "BRL") {
                return response()->json(["code" => 2002, "message" => "Invalid currency"], 400);
            }

            \DB::table('debug')->insert(['text' => 'bmake > ' . json_encode($request)]);

            $Corte  = explode('-', $request->player_id);
            $UserID = $Corte[2];

            $User = null;
            $User = User::Where('id', $UserID)->lockForUpdate()->first();

            if (!$User)
            {
                return response()->json(["code" => 1007, "message" => "Session is expired"], 400);
            }

            if ($User->banned == 1){
                return response()->json(["code" => 1005, "message" => "Player is blocked"], 400);
            }

            if ($User->wallet->balance < $rsamount){
                return response()->json(["code" => 2001, "message" => "Not enough money"], 400);
            }else{
                $User->wallet->balance -= $rsamount;
                $User->wallet->save();
            }

            try {
                $centsamount = $request->amount;
                $rsamount = Helper::convertToRealAmount($centsamount);

                DB::transaction(function () use ($User, $rsamount) {
                    $wallet = DB::table('wallets')->where('user_id', $User->id)->lockForUpdate()->first();

                    if (floatval($wallet->balance) < floatval($rsamount)) {
                        throw new Exception("Saldo insuficiente.");
                    } else {
                        $wallet->balance -= $rsamount;
                        DB::table('wallets')->where('user_id', $User->id)->update(['balance' => $wallet->balance]);
                    }
                });
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                return response()->json(["code" => 2001, "message" => "Not enough money"], 400);
            }

            if (!isset($request->transaction)) {
                return response()->json(["code" => 2004, "message" => "Bad request"], 400);
            }

            $player_id = $request->player_id;
            $session_id = $request->session_id;
            $transaction = $request->transaction;

            $CheckDiscard = SportBetDiscards::Where('transaction_id', $transaction->id)->first();

            if ($CheckDiscard){
                return response()->json(["code" => 2004, "message" => "Bad request"], 400);
            }

            $InfSum = SportBetSummary::create([
                'user_id' => (String)$User->id,
                'transactionId' => $transaction->id,
                'operation' => 'make',
                'status' => 'Pending',
                'statusel' => 'Nil',
                'reason' => 'Nil',
                'amount' => $centsamount,
                'transaction' => json_encode($transaction),
                'betslip' => json_encode($request->betslip->bets),
            ]);

            $balance = $User->wallet->balance;
            $balanceLong = (int)($balance * 100);

            $IDX = $InfSum->id . "-" . time();

            SportBetParents::Create([
                'tId' => $User->id,
                'transaction_id' => $transaction->id,
                'parent' => $IDX,
            ]);

            return response()->json([
                "id" => $IDX,
                "ext_transaction_id" => (string)$transaction->id,
                "parent_transaction_id" => null,
                "user_id" => 'user-id-'.$User->id,//(String)$User->id,
                "operation" => "bet",
                "amount" => $centsamount,
                "currency" => "BRL",
                "balance" => $balanceLong,
            ], 200);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return response()->json(["code" => 2004, "message" => "Bad request"], 400);
        }
    }


It is possible by creating a job for the process using:
php artisan make:job ProcessBetRequest

Then, move the logic into the job's handle() method and set up the queues for sequential processing.
Laravel reference: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queues

Please try this it will be 100% work and the best solution, I have used this job processing for bulk users email sending and push notifications.

Worth noting that queued jobs are not a good choice if you want to instantly return a response of the outcome because they will be picked up when a queue worker is available which depending on system load may take several minutes (or more)

I also told about the queues solution after creating the jobs:
php artisan queue:work

When we set up the queues for sequential processing, it will handle that.

i tried using jobs, but since need use dispatch_now for it retrieve the answer the queue don't work, if i receive 3 requests at same time it process all three at same time. and need queue it and return the answer for back end.

If it is not working, other solution:  could you modify database query with chunk?
https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queries#chunking-results

didn't tried it, ill check. why "lockforupdate" don't lock it or didn't update fastest for queries who run at same second check balance decreased?
